# Delete .php in .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But when I login in my website, I still get **localhost/administration/administration.php**.

I tried .htaccess working, if I insert some random code (like xdxdxd), I get Server Error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: Check your form action type in login use admin file without php.